# Animate specific constraint changes by layoutIfNeeded()

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uibutton

I have programmatically constructed the views and then animating them. There is a chain of view animation and the last one is the button to be animated.

Whilst every thing is working fine as soon as I animate the button by changing the constraints(these constraints are independent of others and no other view has any hinged to it) by calling layoutIfNeeded(), all the views changes and go to their initial position of the animation.

I even tried bunch of other methods such as changing alpha values etc or making it disappear. but every single time, it changes the whole view.

Now, I am not able to figure out the exact cause. Below is the code of it.

Is there a way to change just a specific constraint with `layoutIfNeeded()` or any other way to handle this functionality?

```swift
import UIKit

var nextButton: UIButton!
var nextButtonHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
var nextButtonWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addNextButton()
}

// ..... function trigerred here.
@IBAction func triggerChange() {
    performCaptionAnimation()
}

func addNextButton() {
    nextButton = UIButton()
    nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nextButton.clipsToBounds = true
    nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
    nextButton.backgroundColor = .white
    nextButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    nextButton.titleLabel!.font = AvernirNext(weight: .Bold, size: 16)
    nextButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
    nextButton.roundAllCorners(withRadius: ActionButtonConstraint.height.anchor/2)
    nextButton.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(nextButtonPressed)))
    view.addSubview(nextButton)

    nextButtonHeightConstraint = nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ActionButtonConstraint.height.anchor)
    nextButtonWidthConstraint = nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ActionButtonConstraint.width.anchor)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nextButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: ActionButtonConstraint.right.anchor),
        nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: ActionButtonConstraint.bottom.anchor),
        nextButtonHeightConstraint!, nextButtonWidthConstraint!
        ])
}

func performCaptionAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.bannerTwoItemContainer.alpha = 1
        self.bannerTwoItemContainer.frame.origin.x -= (self.bannerTwoItemContainer.frame.width/2 + 10)
    }) { (done) in
        if done {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.bannerOneItemContainer.alpha = 1
                self.bannerOneItemContainer.frame.origin.x += self.bannerOneItemContainer.frame.width/2 + 10
            }) { (alldone) in
                if alldone {
                    // All changes here ......................
                    self.changeNextButtonContents()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ------ This animation has issues and brings all the animation to it's initial point
func changeNextButtonContents() {
    self.nextButtonHeightConstraint?.constant = 40
    self.nextButtonWidthConstraint?.constant = 110
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
        self.nextButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        self.nextButton.setTitle("Try Now", for: .normal)
        self.nextButton.titleLabel?.font = AvernirNext(weight: .Bold, size: 18)
        self.nextButton.backgroundColor = blueColor
        self.nextButton.roundAllCorners(withRadius: 20)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: you're not animating the constraints,  but frame.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore  Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first animations change their view’s *frame*, as in `self.bannerTwoItemContainer.frame.origin.x`. But you cannot change the frame of something that is positioned by *constraints*. If you do, then as soon as layout occurs, the constraints reassert themselves. That is exactly what you are doing and exactly what happens. You say `layoutIfNeeded` and the constraints, which you never changed, are obeyed.

Rewrite your first animations to change their view’s constraints, not their frame, and all will be well.

Comment: I like to say: frame and constraints are enemies of one another. More technically: constraints are merely a list of instructions, and layout means to obey those instructions. And how does it do that? By changing the frame!

Comment: What should be preferred generally. Constraints(I think this) or the frames, while drawing or animating

Comment: Frame animation is okay for temporary animation, but constraints will always eventually win. So in this case if this rearrangement is only temporary, perhaps you can everything with frames; otherwise you need to figure out how to do everything with constraints.

Comment: Ok. Since this is just a temp animation, I’ll rather remove the constraints for the button itself rather than adding constraints to other views.